# Winforms: Best control to use for listing data quickly

Tags: winforms

I need a control that can list data in 3 columns, I want to manually add the items (not databind the control).....

firstly I'll populate column 1 and 2, then later when a button is clicked, I need to loop through the values of column 1 and 2, perform an operation, then update the value of column 3.

From what I remember the datagrid does not allow for this , and must be bound to a data source, am I right?

What is the best quick drag and drop control I can use from the toolbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a ListView with View property set to Details. Then you can add columns to the listview.

Answer (score 1):

> From what I remember the datagrid does
>   not allow for this , and must be bound
>   to a data source, am I right?

This is not right. The DataGrid can be used in bound or unbound mode. If you don't bind it, you can just add rows and columns and populate cell contents as you need. You could choose to do this if you wish. It will solve your problem.

But I think it would be simpler for you to create a custom class to represent a row and use the DataGrid in bound mode. You can refresh the binding when you click the button.